# Mail Merge Multiple Rows into one document

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I have an excel file with different fields in each column:

Field 1__ | Field 2__ | etc. 
F1 Item 1 | F2 Item 1 | etc. 
F1 Item 2 | F2 Item 2 | etc

each field has a different number of items in it.

I want to create a Word 2010 document that lists all the items in each field into one document and not split into multiple documents for each record.  So the final Word document looks like:

Field 1 
__ F1 Item 1 
__ F1 Item 2 

Field 2 
__ F2 Item 1 
__ F2 Item 2 
__ F2 Item 3

The "Field 1" and "Field 2" Labels would not need to me a mail merge field but all the items under the field would need to be mail merged to displayed in one document.  Is this possible to do, any ideas or resources for how to achieve this?

Comment: I was able to use the { NEXT } command to display all the records for Field 1 but I don't know how to reset the merge record back to 1 for field 2.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a query & reporting tool like SQL Server Reporting Services for this.  You can connect it to an Excel file via ODBC, e.g.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/22/60695.aspx

The report design would have two tables  - one for Field 1 then the next for Field 2. You would need to write two (quite simple) SQL SELECT statements to get the data as two Datasets.

Reporting Services does a nice job of rendering to Word. The layout can be far more complex than a Word mail merge, e.g. multiple data regions, nested sub-reports, complex charts etc.

You can run Reporting Services as a desktop app, embed it in a Windows or Word app or deploy it to a SharePoint site or simple Reporting Services portal.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* be able to use Word's DATABASE field for this. The dialog box for inserting one is not in the ribbon, so you have to go and find it in Word Options and put it in the QAT or some such. But it suffers from one or two problems, so it is probably better to insert the field manually - use ctrl-F9 to insert a pair of the special field brace codes so you have

```
{  }
```

(you can't just type these braces on the keyboard).

Then, everything between the {  } is normal text. Let's suppose let's suppose your Excel document is called c:\xl\mywb.xlsx, the data are in a sheet called Sheet1$ and you have 3 fields called Field1, Field2 and Field3. Then your first DATABASE field can look like this:

```
{ DATABASE  \d "C:\\xl\\mywb.xlsx" \s "SELECT cf1.[field1] FROM [Sheet1$] cf1 WHERE ((cf1.[field1] IS NOT NULL ))" \h }
```

PLease note the doubled-up backslashes in the path name. Once you have entered that, select the field, press F9 to execute it, then use Alt-F9 to look at the results. If they are close to what you need for your first column, this may work OK for you, if they are not, it's probably a good time to give up on this approach. If an error is reported, it's probably because of a typo.

Once you have got one column working, copy/paste the database field and change the names so you have

```
{ DATABASE  \d "C:\\xl\\mywb.xlsx" \s "SELECT cf1.[field1] FROM [Sheet1$] cf1 WHERE ((cf1.[field1] IS NOT NULL ))" \h }

{ DATABASE  \d "C:\\xl\\mywb.xlsx" \s "SELECT cf2.[field2] FROM [Sheet1$] cf2 WHERE ((cf2.[field2] IS NOT NULL ))" \h }
```

then select, F9, Alt-F9 again. If all is well, repeat for the remaining fields.

A few notes:

WHERE ((cf2.[field2] IS NOT NULL )) is there to deal with the fact that your columns have different numbers of cells in them. But you may need a little more than that, and this technique will eliminate *all* blank cells, not just empty cells at the bottom of the column.

\h just adds a column header.

the "cf1", "cf2" are SQL "TABLE alias names". You can invent them as required. They should not be needed, but they are there because without them Word tends to get a bit confused, as you may discover if you try to insert these fields using the DATABASE field dialog box (which does not insert these alias names).

Comment: I've tried doing this but I get the error message "Word was unable to open the data source."  And a window comes up telling me to select the data source.  When I select the excel file i get the error message "Error has occurred: No value given for one or more required parameters.  Is this a problem with my code? My code is `{ DATABASE \d "\\tr\\tr\\path\\excelfile.xlsm" \s "SELECT cf1.[ Primary_Details] FROM [Sheet6$] cf1 WHERE ((cf1.[Primary_Details] IS NOT NULL ))" \h }`

Comment: What is the actual path to your .xlsm? (not necessarily what I see in your comment, but as it stands it is unlikely to work). If you actually have a space in your first [ Primary_Details] you will need to delete that too. Finally, I have a horrible feeling that this will only work with a .xlsx, not a .xlsm (but that may be a Mac Office perspective).

Comment: I got it to work! The extra space was causing the error.  When I use F9 to run the code a window pops up asking me for the data source.  Will I need to use F9 and select the data source for each field (very time consuming) every time I want run the report, or is there another way to "refresh" it when the data in the excel file changes?

Comment: Normally the full Excel path+file name and the correct sheet name (or named range) are enough. I would guess that there is either still something wrong with the file name. If it's a UNC server-share name, you will need to double up the backslashes att he beginning (i.e. you need four backslashes at the beginning. All I can suggest is that if it does not work for that file, you could verify that it works in principle with a newly created test .xlsx, then decide whether it is worth your while to pursue it any further.